# Fast and proper accessing

Tags: c#

I am creating a game, where each player controls a class Country. The Country has 
a `list of MilitaryUnits`. The `MilitaryUnits` have locations on a 2 dimensional map. If I want to get the `MilitaryUnit` on location(2,3), and then see to which country he belongs, I need to have a field in class `MilitaryUnit` with his owner country, but in this way two classes are going to point to each other. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand the code if you would *show* it (just a minimal example) instead of *describing* it.

Comment: Start with the fact that it is logical that a Military Unit knows what Country it is fighting for.

Comment: It's generally not a problem in C# if two classes point to each other because garbage collection deals with this. However in this implementation you will have to loop through all existing units to find the ones you want. Think about maintaining an index by map coordinates of some sort.

Comment: You have a Country, Player, MilitaryUnit, and Map. Now figure out the relations between all these 4. Start with a mind map and make statements that are facts like "Player has control of MilitaryUnit(S)" etc.

Comment: Is it going to be bad if I leave it that way( two classes pointing to each other ), because it really is logical the Military Unit to know for who he is fighting for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a bidirectional mapping, you have to store that pieces of information somewhere. (So you need two pointers/references/etc.)
I don't know the exact architecture and algorithms of your software, but I think the proper place for these bits of information is exactly in the classes which are referencing each other. (Specially in an object-oriented design.)

If this referencing is causing a problem, you can use external mappings (outside of the mentioned classes), like

```
Dictionary<MilitaryUnit,Country> UnitToCountry;
Dictionary<Country, Set<MilitaryUnit>> CountryToUnits;
```

But this is not better, or most efficient, but may be needed in some software architectures.

So, if you go with C#, and it does not cause architectural problems for you, I think it's totally ok to reference two classes from each other.